# Updating old personas within an existing product

Tags: user-research, users, personas, user-interviews

What kind of a way do you choose to update the old personas of an existing product?

1. Interview and gather qualitative data from a wide range of random users of the product and then create personas between them.
2. Consider old persona feature patterns and interview with these target group only (A feature pattern example; newly graduated personas, experienced personas etc.)

By the way, the reason for updating the old personas is that old ones have a lot of missing information and also have old fashion persona template.

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to update personas to reflect your current target group. The world around your target group is changing and so should your personas.

So I would recommend using option 1; Have new interviews with your target group. Learn from the gaps and valuable information from the previous personas and ask the right questions to get that information. If you have the resources interview some edge cases and current expert users of the product.

After conducting the interviews see if your target group changed. If so, write down the changes and the effects it has on the product. Present this information to you client or manager. You can also use this information again after X years to talk to your client or manager to update the personas and the product.

I hope this helps out!

Answer (score 0):

A good product design practice has made significant strides in facilitating the good development of products that satisfy individual needs and are easy to use. While User-Centered Design (UCD) takes place as a popular development methodology, the usability of products, systems and many User Interfaces (UI) has improved. An alternative method for representing and communicating customers needs from a product is the use of *personas*. By using a name, picture and narrative, a *persona* provide product designers and developers with a vivid representation of the target and of the focus group.

[image]

[Steve Barnett](https://naga.co.za/) show us from the [User-Centered Design process](https://naga.co.za/2015/08/20/user-centered-design-process-2/) article that a process to create and update a *personas* can be sketched and should contain at least the following information:

- Picture
- Name
- Quote
- Job title

[image]

**The Answer**

You might choose option (1.) if you conclude that you have a generic new group of customers to update your *personas*. Or you might choose option (2.) if you out of budget and time or you still maintain the same user profile characteristics.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer Francisco.

I think I need to consider Lean Personas and understand the method well and apply. Otherwise, I don't have enough budget and especially time in agile environment.